# Surface of Revolution

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pgfplots

[image]how to draw using surface of revolution tikz or pgfplots?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am not able to reproduce a surface like this. Can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: You should open a new question for this, instead of changing your existing one and unaccepting the answer.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @Jake, in the new question you should at least make an attempt in adapting the solution below to this new problem as they are clearly related.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the plots below I've given two demonstrations: one is a surface rotated around the y-axis, and one is rotated around the x-axis

The main trick is to parametrize the surface appropriately using the sine and cosine functions.

When you rotate the function `f(t)` around the y-axis, then you let

```
x(t,s) = t*cos(s)
y(t,s) = t*sin(s)
z(t,s) = f(t)
```

If you want to rotate the function `f(t)` around the x-axis, then you let

```
x(t,s) = t
y(t,s) = f(t)*cos(s)
z(t,s) = f(t)*sin(s)
```

Typically `s` will be on the interval `[0,2\pi]`, and you can choose your interval for `t` as you like.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

% rotated around the y-axis
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
  samples=20,
  domain=1:2,y domain=0:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({x * cos(deg(y))}, {x * sin(deg(y))}, {1/x});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% rotated around the x-axis
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
  samples=20,
  domain=1:2,y domain=0:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  (x,{(1/x) * cos(deg(y))}, {(1/x) * sin(deg(y))});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

Following the question edit

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={60}{30}]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=flat,
  samples=20,
  domain=0:2*pi,y domain=0:2*pi,
  z buffer=sort]
  ({x * cos(deg(y))}, {x * sin(deg(y))}, {cos(deg(x))});
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: You're welcome; you can tweak some further options such as `label`, perhaps even transparency, but this code gives the main idea :)

Comment: New help, please.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva I'm very happy to help, but it seems a little unfair to un-accept my answer now that you've changed the question. I did answer the original question.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva See the update

Comment: Hmm ... [that one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rotationskoerper_animation.gif) looks much nicer. Let's see if I can recreate it with TikZ and your answer.

Comment: Update: recent versions of pgfplots allow to use builtin coordinate systems. A good extension to this answer could be to rely on `data cs=polarrad` and specify the input coordinates in the coordinate system `<angle>,<radius>,<Z>` . See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173602/pgfplots-3d-creating-a-filled-solid-of-revolution/174077#174077 for another application