# Draw closed section of sphere using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I want to draw a section of a sphere to represent its volume.

I have currently got the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 10cm,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    view/h=45,
]
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=21,
    domain=0:1,
    y domain=0:0.5*pi,
    z buffer=sort]
 ({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
 {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))},
 x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me:

[image: thing]

But I want the sides to be closed, something like this:
[image: thing2]

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! It is great you've provided code. Could you complete it so potential helpers can copy-paste a compilable document?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173602/pgfplots-3d-creating-a-filled-solid-of-revolution/174077#174077

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A first - though simple - approach - would be to treat all 3 sides as surfaces themselves. So by just setting one or another component to 0, one would obtain

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 10cm,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    view/h=45,
]
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=21,domain=0:1,
    y domain=0:0.5*pi,z buffer=sort]
 (0, {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))}, x);
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=21, domain=0:1, y domain=0:0.5*pi, z buffer=sort]
 ({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))}, {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))}, x);
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=21, domain=0:1, y domain=0:0.5*pi, z buffer=sort]
 ({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},0, x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: First try]

I had to order them the right way, because they aren't z-buffered with respect to each other. And - in my opinion - using the standard color map might be misleading in the resulting images 3d effect.

Comment: I think Ronny forgot the bottom surface here. If you compare his finished plot with the grayscale one of the OP's question, the bottom panel is absent.

Comment: You're right; but that 3rd plane can be copy pasted from the other ones :)

Comment: @Ronny - Is it possible to draw 2D shapes on this 3D structure?

Comment: That depends; but I think in most cases – yes :) better open a new question for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can improve the answer from [Ronny](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212446/134085) by adding these lines:

```
every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
every axis y label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
every axis z label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}}
```

With these lines the labels will be closer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal,
axis lines = center,
width = 10cm,
height = 10cm,
xlabel = {$x$},
ylabel = {$y$},
zlabel = {$z$},
zmax=1.1,
view/h=45,
every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
every axis y label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}},
every axis z label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}}
]
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,samples=21, domain=0:1, y domain=0:0.5*pi, z buffer=sort](0, {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))}, x);
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,samples=21, domain=0:1, y domain=0:0.5*pi, z buffer=sort]({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))}, {sqrt( 1-x^2 ) * sin(deg(y))}, x);
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,samples=21, domain=0:1, y domain=0:0.5*pi, z buffer=sort]({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},0, x);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Solution by [JPi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43843/jpi)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis lines = center,
    width = 10cm,
    height = 10cm,
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    zlabel = {$z$},
    view/h=45,
]
\addplot3[surf, opacity = 0.5,
    samples=21,
    domain=0:1,
    y domain=0:0.5*pi,
    z buffer=sort]
 ({sqrt(1-x^2) * cos(deg(y))},
 {sqrt(1-x^2) * sin(deg(y))},
 x);
    
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 0, {sqrt(1-0.4^2) * cos(deg(0.25*pi))}, 0.4) -- (axis cs: 1, {sqrt(1-0.4^2) * cos(deg(0.25*pi))}, 0.4);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 1, {sqrt(1-0.4^2) * cos(deg(0.25*pi))}, 0.4) -- (axis cs: 1, 0, 0.4);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 1, 0, 0.4) -- (axis cs: 0, 0, 0.4);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs: 0, 0, 0.4) -- (axis cs: 0, {sqrt(1-0.4^2) * cos(deg(0.25*pi))}, 0.4);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and your other answer?