# pgfplots: rotating a shape in 3D independent of the axes

Tags: pgfplots, rotating, 3d

I have a group of shapes I'm plotting in 3D via `\addplot3` (such as a cone) and need to have them pointed in a direction specified by the macro arguments. I do *not* want to just change the view angle or rotate the whole plot/axes as I'll be plotting other stuff that I want to just plot normally. Is there an easy way to do this (rotate my cone and other shapes) via some argument to `\addplot3` or something else? Or do I have to manually do this in the equations? (I'm doubting there's anything, but I figured I'd give it a shot before doing it via the equations. =P)

For my MWE, here is my cone that I'd like to rotate:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center, axis on top, samples=30,
     xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5, ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=0.0]
\addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=0:1, y domain=0:2*pi] ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could try changing the unit vectors for `x`, `y` and `z`. I am not sure it can be done with `\addplot3` but might be worth looking into.

Comment: I believe you'll have to set up the transformation equations on your own. You could insert them into a suitable `filter point` macro which takes `\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}` and `../y`, `../z`, respectively and reads the result from these values. Also see the related (yet not the same approach) idea in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173602/pgfplots-3d-creating-a-filled-solid-of-revolution/174077#174077 . But the equations as such are not in `pgfplots`.