# PGFPlots — a solid of revolution as a 2D-plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw something like this:

[image: Sample]

And I probably should use a 3D-plot as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173602/pgfplots-3d-creating-a-filled-solid-of-revolution) but it seems to be an overkill solution in my case. So I wonder if there is a better way to draw ellipses than mine solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=0.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    xmin=-0.2,
    xmax=7.5,
    ymin=-1.2,
    ymax=1.2,
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    xticklabel=\empty,
    ytick={-1, 1},  
    height=80mm,
    width=100mm,
]

    \addplot[peter_river, line width=0.25mm, mark=none, samples=150, domain=0:7] {1/x};
    \addplot[peter_river, line width=0.25mm, mark=none, samples=150, domain=0:7] {-1/x};



    \node[font=\small, anchor=east] at (axis cs:7, 1) {$\pi\cdot\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}{\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^2}dx$}; 

    \draw[] (axis cs:2, 0) ellipse (20 and 10);

    \draw[] (axis cs:1, 1) -- (axis cs:2, 1);
    \draw[] (axis cs:1, -1) -- (axis cs:2, -1);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:1, -1) rectangle (axis cs:1.5, 1);
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:1, 0) ellipse (20 and 10);
    \end{scope}     
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:1, -1) rectangle (axis cs:0.5, 1);
        \draw[] (axis cs:1, 0) ellipse (20 and 10);
    \end{scope} 

    \draw[] (axis cs:4, 0) ellipse (10 and 5);

    \draw[] (axis cs:2, 0.5) -- (axis cs:4, 0.5);
    \draw[] (axis cs:2, -0.5) -- (axis cs:4, -0.5);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:2, -1) rectangle (axis cs:2.5, 1);         
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:2, 0) ellipse (10 and 5);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:2, -1) rectangle (axis cs:1.5, 1);         
        \draw[] (axis cs:2, 0) ellipse (10 and 5);
    \end{scope}

    \draw[] (axis cs:4, 0.25) -- (axis cs:7, 0.25);
    \draw[] (axis cs:4, -0.25) -- (axis cs:7, -0.25);
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:4, -1) rectangle (axis cs:4.5, 1);         
        \draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, 0) ellipse (5 and 2.5);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip[] (axis cs:4, -1) rectangle (axis cs:1.5, 1);         
        \draw[] (axis cs:4, 0) ellipse (5 and 2.5);
    \end{scope}

    \node[font=\small] at (axis cs:1.5, 1.1) {$\pi$};   
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:3, 0.65) {$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}$};    
    \node[font=\scriptsize] at (axis cs:5.5, 0.4) {$\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$};   

    \draw[-stealth] (axis cs:0.5, 0.05) to[out=90, in=-20] (axis cs:0.35, 0.15) 
                        to[out=200, in=90] (axis cs:0.2, 0) 
                        to[out=270, in=160] (axis cs:0.35, -0.2)
                        to[out=20, in=270] (axis cs:0.5, -0.05);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ugly solution]

Comment: the reason for the need of 1.11 is that before the default coordinate system  in the axes environment was different (you have to add `axis cs:` to the ellipse coordinates to run it in previous versions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  It's a bit less structured perhaps than PGFplots+Tikz, and maybe this gives you more artistic freedom, for this sort of semi-numerical diagram.  I would recommend Asymptote for anything more demanding in 3D than these cyclinders.

In this example, I've used [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en) to make it easier to typeset using Palatino as in the OP, so this should be compiled with `lualatex`.  If you don't use `lualatex` for your main document, you can either use it to produce a standalone PDF graphic from this example, or adapt the input either to use the `gmp` package (which works with `pdflatex`) or run Metapost on it's own.  See the linked documentation for details.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric u, v; 
u = 3cm;
v = 2cm;

path xx, yy;
xx = (1/4 left -- 19/4 right) scaled u;
yy = (3/2 down -- 3/2 up) scaled v;

drawarrow xx;
drawarrow yy;

draw (left--right) scaled 2 shifted (0,v);
draw (left--right) scaled 2 shifted (0,-v);
label.lft("$1$", (-2,v));
label.lft("$-1$", (-2,-v));

vardef f(expr x) = if x=0: infinity else: (1/x)**2 fi enddef;
path ff;
numeric s;
s = 1/16;
ff = ((12s, f(12s)) for x=13s step s until 73s+eps: -- (x,f(x)) endfor ) 
     xscaled u yscaled v;


path e[]; 
e0 = fullcircle rotated 90 xscaled 24;
e1 = e0 yscaled 2(f(1)*v)   shifted (1u,0);   e2 = e1 shifted (1/2u,0);

e3 = e0 xscaled 1/3;
e4 = e3 yscaled 2(f(3/2)*v) shifted (3/2u,0); e5 = e4 shifted (   u,0);

e6 = e3 xscaled 1/4;
e7 = e6 yscaled 2(f(5/2)*v) shifted (5/2u,0); e8 = e7 shifted (   2u,0);


drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled .2 withcolor .7 white);
for t= s step  s until 4: draw point t of e1 -- point t of e2; endfor
drawoptions();
draw e2 -- subpath (0,4) of e1 -- point 4 of e2;

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled .2 withcolor .7 white);
for t=2s step 2s until 4: draw point t of e4 -- point t of e5; endfor
drawoptions();
draw e5 -- subpath (0,4) of e4 -- point 4 of e5;

drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled .2 withcolor .7 white);
for t=4s step 4s until 4: draw point t of e7 -- point t of e8; endfor
drawoptions();
draw point 0 of e8 -- subpath (0,4) of e7 -- point 4 of e8;

draw ff withcolor .67 red;
draw ff reflectedabout(left,right) withcolor .67 red;


drawarrow subpath(-3/2,11/2) of e0 xscaled 1/2 yscaled v shifted (1/2u,0);

label.rt ("$x$", point 1 of xx);
label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

label(textext("$\displaystyle \pi \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$") scaled 1.2, (4u,5/4v));

label.top("$\pi$",   1/2[point 0 of e1, point 0 of e2]);
label.top("$\pi/2$", 1/2[point 0 of e4, point 0 of e5]);
label.top("$\pi/4$", 1/2[point 0 of e7, point 0 of e8]);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have no experience with Metapost at all but the result looks great! Thank you!